# How does xhci_urb_enqueue() know which endpoint to send the control request to in Linux USB stack?

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, libusb, usb-drive

I am trying to understand how `xhci_urb_enqueue()` figures out what is the endpoint address to forward control requests. From the code it calls `ep_index = xhci_get_endpoint_index(&urb->ep->desc)` to get ep_index which eventually uses `epd->bEndpointAddress & USB_ENDPOINT_NUMBER_MASK` to determine the endpoint address.

My understanding is that control requests to get `device/configuration/interface /endpoint descriptors` are only answered by ep0 and after that host issues `Set_Address/Set_configuration` to the device, from that point on all control requests should be sent to the actually endpoint address mentioned in the endpoint descriptor.

My questions are:

1. Is the USB device supposed to bring up endpoints after receiving Set_configuration request?
2. How and when is `epd->bEndpointAddress` set during the setup stage mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out `ep_index` is changed based on what device driver/XHCI read from the descriptors. During setup stage only control requests are being passed to usb device so `ep_index` is always 0 `(urb_pipetype(urb) == PIPE_CONTROL)`, this is based on USB protocol design. Once setup stage completes, `ep_index` always returns the correct endpoint index for bulk/int transfer requests `(urb_pipetype(urb) == PIPE_BULK | PIPE_INTERRUPT`.